# ubuntu can't get correct ip config from router

Tags: internet, ip

At a point, all my network settings went crazy. nameserver point to 192.168.0.1, and ip address is 192.168.0.xxx. nslookup no response (Can't resolve any address). Can't ping any address.

While another computer under the same network has ip address 10.1.24.xx. I tried to change /etc/resolv.conf but get no luck.

Can anyone help me out? Or I need to reinstall ubuntu?

UPDATE:

I'm using DHCP through wireless.

Comment: Could you update your question with the output of `nm-tool`? Also, are you using DHCP? Cable or wireless?

Answer (score 1):

## Stage 1: Get a Connection

I'd first try to configure your nic via DHCP:

> sudo dhclient

After that, I'd expect your machine to have an IP similar to your other machine, *10.1.24.XY*

You can check what your router IP is by running

> route -n | grep UG

I wager your default gateway (router) is at *10.1.24.1* - ping it to verify it's working okay.

If dhclient didn't get you an IP, manually set one:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 10.1.24.200 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 255.255.255.0 
sudo route add default gw 10.1.24.1
```

I hope that gives you a good feel.

## Stage 2: Make it persist

I'd wager you should just goof with your network manager settings.

If you want to manually configure your nic, edit */etc/network/interfaces*

Most users will want to edit their persistent network settings via the network manager: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager

Comment: I did manually set and it can conner to internet now. But the problem is once I restart the system, I need to redo the manually setting, anyway to solve the problem?

Comment: @SnowWolf: Most users will permanently set their network settings through the Network Manager. There's typically an icon for it near the clock on your toolbar. Here's a link to general documentation on using both the graphical part of the nm and the command-line part of it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager